# Moving Editor upward in .NET MAUI chat app

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI app -- targeting .NET 7 -- I've been successfully moving my `Entry` controls up using `TranslateTo(0, -75, 100)` so that the soft keyboard doesn't cover them up.

In my chat page, however, it doesn't seem to work. Here's how the page is structured:

```
<Grid
  RowDefinitions="*,Auto">

  <CollectionView
      Grid.Row="0">
   ... messages here
  <CollectionView>

  <Grid
      x:Name="EntrySectionGrid"
      Grid.Row="1"
      RowDefinitions="50"
      ColumnDefinitions="*,50"
      RowSpacing="0"
      ColumnSpacing="5"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      Margin="5,5,5,5">
      <Editor
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="0"
          BackgroundColor="{StaticResource White}"
          TextColor="{StaticResource Gray900}"
          Text="{Binding Message}"
          AutoSize="TextChanges"
          Focused="ShiftGridUpward"
          Unfocused="ShiftGridDownward"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
      <Button
         Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Text="Send"
         Command={Binding SendCommand}/>
  </Grid>

</Grid>
```

And in my code behind, I have these two methods:

```
private void ShiftGridUpward(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    if (DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        EntrySectionGrid.TranslateTo(0, -75, 100);
}

private void ShiftGridDownward(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    if (DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        EntrySectionGrid.TranslateTo(0, 0, 100);
}
```

As mentioned before, this has always worked fine but in this layout it's not. I thought it's probably the `RowDefinitions="*,Auto"` in the outer `Grid` causing the issue but so far I haven't been able to get it work.

I'm sure others have tackled a chat layout before. I'd appreciate some suggestions on fixing this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered trying other layouts instead of Grid?

Comment: No, I haven't. I thought `Grid` was the "preferred" approach in .NET MAUI. Wouldn't it be harder to keep the entry at the bottom of the screen with, say, `VerticalStackLayout`?

Comment: Try adding a dummy third row, to push everything up. Start out with height 0, then change to 75 when keyboard appears.